# APNs does not work in iOS 8.0 and later using UIUserNotificationSettings

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8, apple-push-notifications

I am actually developing an app for iPhone and iPad.

I am implementing the APNs, and it works for iOS < 8.0. Looking for in Stackoverflow I found a lot of questions about it and the way to implement APNs for iOS 8.0 and later, and I just follow this steps.

My code is:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [self registerForRemoteNotification];
  return YES;
}

- (void)registerForRemoteNotification 
{
  if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
                                        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
  } else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
  }
}

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
   //register to receive notifications
   [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
   NSLog(@"Active notifications: %@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings]);
}
#endif
```

When I check the active notifications it returns me "UIUserNotificationSettings: 0x156c03e0; types: (none);" and I don't understand why and the log is still show me "Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission from the user to badge the application".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a line code for iOS8:

**[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];**

Like this:

```
if ([application respondsToSelector: selector (registerUserNotificationSettings :)]) {
      UIUserNotificationSettings * settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes: UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                                                               categories: nil ];
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings: settings];
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
   } else {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
        UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
        UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
        UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];

   }
```

Comment: Thank you @TonyMkenu, I am going to change it, but I found my error, the application was disabled permissions for the notifications in the device. :( this was my fault

Comment: in iOS8 you MUST add that line (registerForRemoteNotifications) if you want to receive the notifications :)